# How do I set up the continuations for HttpClient correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, httpclient

I'm using .NET 4.0, so I can't use the async/await keywords.

After I laboriously set up tasks and continuations instead of just calling .Result, all I got for my efforts was a mess and it runs 46% slower on a workload of a few dozen HTTP GETs. (I get similar perf degradation if I call the workload in serial or in a Parallel loop)

What must I do to see any performance benefit?

```
//Slower code
public UserProfileViewModel GetAsync(Guid id)
{
    UserProfileViewModel obj = null;//Closure
    Task result = client.GetAsync(id.ToString()).ContinueWith(responseMessage =>
    {
            Task<string> stringTask = responseMessage.Result
                                            .Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Task continuation = stringTask.ContinueWith(responseBody =>
            {
                obj = JsonConvert
                     .DeserializeObject<UserProfileViewModel>(responseBody.Result);
            });
            //This is a child task, must wait before returning to parent.
            continuation.Wait();
        });
    result.Wait();
    return obj;
}

//Faster code
public UserProfileViewModel GetSynchr(Guid id)
{
    //Asych? What's is that?
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(id.ToString()).Result;
    string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfileViewModel>(responseBody);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using "async" methods but doing everything synchronously. That certainly won't be any better than doing everything synchronously with the synchronous methods.

Take a look at this:

```
public Task<UserProfileViewModel> GetAsync(Guid id)
{
    var uri = id.ToString();
    return client.GetAsync(uri).ContinueWith(responseTask =>
    {
        var response = responseTask.Result;
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(jsonTask =>
        {
            var json = jsonTask.Result;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfileViewModel>(json);
        });
    }).Unwrap();
}
```

Notice how the method returns a `Task` and the continuations are returned from the method. This allows your method to return almost instantly, giving the caller a handle to the running work *and* whatever continuations need to happen. The returned task will only be complete once everything is done, and it's result will be your `UserProfileViewModel`.

The `Unwrap` method takes a `Task<Task<UserProfileViewModel>>` and turns it into a `Task<UserProfileViewModel>`.

Comment: Your `Unwrap` method is a pretty poor implementation, especially considering there's an implementation baked into .NET that does it correctly.

Comment: @Servy I mistakenly thought it was only in .NET 4.5. I removed the quick and dirty implementation since it's in .NET 4.0 (the version the OP asked for).

Comment: Even if it were, your implementation relies on .NET 4.5 methods anyway.

Comment: @Servy It was browser code and it's gone now. It should have been `Task.Factory.StartNew` not `Task.Run`.

Comment: That's more like it, 5 times faster than serial, and 2x faster than calling .Result.

Comment: @MatthewMartin Glad to have helped. :) Typically any calls to `Wait()` or `Result`, which block the current thread, are indicators that the asynchronous coding is wrong.

Comment: I know this is more than 5 years old, but I tried implementing this and the line "var response = responseTask.Result;" throws an exception.  On inspection, the responseTask object is Status = Canceled.  Has something changed from .Net 4 to 4.7?